# Get started with nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

can you suggest me any sources where they could explain using nhibernate for dummies?

I don't even know which version to download or visual studio 2008 and where?

and how to use it after download, where to put dll files and stuff?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend Steven Bohlen's excellent series [Summer of NHibernate](http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/)

Comment: this was extremely helpful for me.

Comment: ... and he's in the middle of another great one: Autumn of Agile at http://www.autumnofagile.net/

Answer (score 1):

Check out Nhibernate in Action from manning publication...

[NHibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/kuate/)

Answer (score 0):

The [NHibernate Faq Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20110227204838/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/Default.aspx) is a good beginner resource. Go all the way back to the posts in march 2008 for a beginner's introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at http://fluentnhibernate.org/